# How to open bluetooth settings screen

Tags: iphone, ios6

I am using this code to open Bluetooth screen settings:

`NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=General&path=Bluetooth"];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: url];`

But it's not working, I am using iOS 6.0 SDK

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean? What did you expect to see, and what happened?

Comment: it doen't open setting - screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe opening the settings app is deprecated in iOS 5.1.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like all programmatic ways are either through urls (only works on 5.0 exactly), or directly modifying settings (non-public api).

However, it must also be possible somehow on 5.1+, as for example the "Runtastic"-App does exactly this (shows dialog that asks if you want to open bluetooth settings) when you start it.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3.0 & iOS 10 and above

```
func openBluetoothSettings(){
        let urlBTSet = URL(string: "App-Prefs:root=Bluetooth")
        let objApp = UIApplication.shared
        objApp.openURL(urlBTSet!)
    }
```

Objective-c

```
-(void) openBluetoothSettings{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"App-Prefs:root=Bluetooth"]];
}
```

So, In above code what they have changed is string need to add "App-Prefs:root=Bluetooth" (This the example of opening bluetooth settings)

Don't forgot : 'Goto taget -> info -> URL Types -> Add "prefs" in URL Schemes'

Comment: for more details please check : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41895271/2006503

Answer (score 0):

It's question for iOS 6.0 but for iOS 8/9 here is the answer,

Go to your XCode project, under Info -> URL Types section -> "prefs" in URL Scheme

> In IOS9: let url = NSURL(string: "prefs:root=Bluetooth")!
>
> IOS8: let url = NSURL(string: "prefs:root=General&path=Bluetooth")!