# How can I jump to system wifi list in ios10?

Tags: ios

in older version, we use `[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"]`, but in iOS10, it doesn't function.

Comment: learn how to ask a good question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Its not working in ios 10 any more,

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/49730

Refer this link.

Comment: No answers in that thread. Do you know the solution on ios10?

Comment: It is not possible anymore. Wasn't officially supported anyway.

Comment: There is no solutions yet. Its not supported by apple now. @Kent

Comment: Know it. Wayward Apple.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't officially supported at any point anyway.
Check this [link on stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37940472/custom-url-scheme-for-settings-on-ios-10) for further information.